# Logstash-Slack plugin configuration problems

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, slack-api, logstash-configuration

I am trying to use Logstash-Slack plugin with this configuration:

```
slack {
  url => "..."
  channel => ["..."]
  attachments => [ {"color" => "#36a64f"},{"title" => "This is a title %{title}"},{"author_name" => %{name}} ]
}
```

But when I receive a message with attachment, the color was not set properly and the variables values `title` and `name` are displayed as `%{title}` and `%{name}`.

Have anybody successfully configured this plugin? What should be the proper settings?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem. I am also facing the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My Grok filter was this:

```
 grok {
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} Thread:'(?<thread>[^']+)' Level:'%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}' Message:%{GREEDYDATA:information}"]
```

And I was able to fix the problem by using this in the message:

```
slack
        {
           url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
           format => "%{log-level} at %{@timestamp} on %{type} \n\n Message: %{information}"
        }
```

Note:  Attachments still don't work also \n doesnt break the line and its just displayed in Slack as \n

My Error message logs a multiline large chunks of text, so i really wanted to do something like this, which offcourse isnt working:

```
slack
        {
           url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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"
           format => "%{log-level} at %{@timestamp} on %{type} with IP:%{host}"
           attachments => "Message: %{information}"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

see:
https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1645

-> "workarounds today" -> newline: use an actual newline character

tested and validated with logstash-5.5.0 + logstash-output-slack-2.0.3